# "it's" should be changed to "its" on help center "How do I create an account?" page

Tags: bug, status-completed, help-center, grammar

In the help center's [how do I create an account?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/creating-accounts) page there is the following text:

> In addition to creating an account for this site (and it’s associated meta-discussion site)...

This should be written as follows because the possessive form is being used:

> In addition to creating an account for this site (and its associated meta-discussion site)...

Comment: What is this I don't even

Comment: Apostrophe's are terrible things to waste.

Comment: Its's is a slightly silly error, isn't's sits?

Comment: Well, I, for one, have never seen so many similar error in my life then on these site's. It effects me so vary greatly.

Comment: It greetly offsets me too here a bout these. Eye de-manned they bee corected imeditly!

Comment: ["As I've written documents over the years, there are times when I use an apostrophe S, and it seems like I'm supposed to use an apostrophe S. But I have to say that my grammar is not strong enough to tell you right now with clarity when an apostrophe S is used." - Chris Crawford](http://www.thisamericanlife.org/radio-archives/episode/496/transcript)

Comment: Beware of *[Jeff Atwood's Big-S](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/63791#63791)*.

Comment: Hi Robert, did you see the answer?

Comment: @bad_coder yes but it's status-completed so I don't see why it needs an answer.

Comment: @RobertLongson ups sorry, this was discussed with the mods and they agreed a solved question is still better if it has an answer than not because that way it doesn't pollute the search results as unanswered and gives a visual solution of what things look like. (Of the 12,7k status-completed only 400 are unanswered so I thought I might take a few.) Also [a recent Q](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/379774) was received favorably, and it's how the rest of the site also works.

Answer (score 1):

This has been fixed and the sentence is now written using the possessive form in the help center, as shown in the screenshot:

[image: screenshot of my account page in the help center]