# Should I answer questions tagged [status-completed] that are unanswered?

Tags: discussion, answers, meta

Should I answer to status-completed questions and say this? I saw someone do something similar:

> This is [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed). (Upvote this answer to remove it from unanswered questions page)

Should I follow along?

Comment: Where did you see that quote *"Upvote this answer to remove it from unanswered questions page"*? Unanswered questions don't have any answers to vote on I think?!

Comment: @bad_coder sorry I lost the link, I am trying to find it. My bad :(

Comment: Just curious with two opposing answers, what made you accept one and not the other? If score only, you might reconsider now that they're in a tie.

Comment: I found pandas answer better, especially since I tried adding info to old posts but ended up getting removed

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, this is pointless unless your answer adds value by elaborating on how the issue at hand is resolved. Adding value can be in the form of adding screenshots, an explanation on any new behaviour, etc.

By simply saying "this is [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)" defeats the purpose of having such a tag in the first place.

Comment: I've seen mods, staff and users do as the OP proposes after the fact and I support that course of action. It makes the site tidier and reduces pollution in search results.

Answer (score 5):

I think it's a good idea to post such answers, but only in specific, limited cases.

One case where I've done so is with a request that was tagged as [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) but had a negative score and no answers, and would have been automatically deleted otherwise. I posted the answer because I didn't want to see the record of the feature change get wiped.

Another case where I'd answer a request with the [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) tag is when a request is completed but not in the exact manner specified in the request, and the staff explanation as to how was posted as a comment that's been buried in other comments. In that case, I'd post an answer with a quote of the comment and a link to it.

Finally, I've posted quite a few answers to completed requests that for some reason weren't actually tagged as completed. This use of answers [was explicitly approved by a community manager](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=9031424#9031424). See also [How do I answer a bug report?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/325663/how-do-i-answer-a-bug-report)

Answer (score 4):

If a question has been marked [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) but has never been answered then yes, you can answer it in order to give the question some closure and removed it from the unanswered questions listing.

However, please be careful not to mass answer too many such questions in a short time as to not bump the front page. And, also, verify if staff have posted the solution elsewhere and if the question should be closed as a duplicate. You can try to add some value by including screenshots of before/after (using the [Wayback Machine](https://archive.org/web/)) where that makes sense.

At the time of this writing there are 987 such question using the search [`[status-completed] is:q answers:0`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bstatus-completed%5D+is:q+answers:0).

Comment: I've done this before on a question that had been tagged as completed by staff but had a negative score and no answers, and was thus subject to automatic deletion, in order to ensure that the record of the change wasn't lost.

Comment: @SonictheSaveUkraine-hog I think that comment alone makes for an excellent answer!! Consider converting to answer.